# what percentage was used?

Tags: php, math

here is an example of what I mean

```
function t1(){
    $n = 875;
    $p = 12;
    $b = $n*($p/100);
    $a = $n-$b;
    return array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b);
}

$v1 = t1();
```

now from `$v1` we can tell that `$n` was `$v1['a']+$v1['b'];`

but how do we work out what `$p` was?

Comment: This is more math-related than PHP-related.  The question (and answer) will be pretty much the same regardless of language.

Comment: note that this is not the actual code, the function is simply there to point out the fact that the other code does not know what $n and $p initially were

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, from a purely mathematical point of view, 100 * b / (a + b) is the percentage. As to how that is written in php, I'm not sure. Is this a homework question?

Comment: no its not a homework question. Im not even at school, cheers.

Comment: its actually because we are taking a control group, but we only store the amount of users in the control `$b` and the number of user- the control `$a` but now we need to work out what percentage was selected.

Comment: Well, p controls the proportion allocated between b and a. So you just need to look at that. The equation I wrote is correct, but you'll need to work out how to write it in PHP, since I'm a java person myself. Oh, and if the sample size is small enough, you may not be able to recover p precisely, as there may be several values that would result in the same allocation between a and b.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can solve:

`$b = $n * ($p/100)`

Implies ($n = $a +$b):

`$v1['b'] / ($v1['a']+$v1['b']) = $p / 100`

Implies:

`$p = 100 *$v1['b'] / ($v1['a'] +$v1['b'])`

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you have:

`a = n-b`

and

`b = n * p / 100`

Rearranging the first, you see that `n = a + b`. Substituting `a+b` for `n` in the second equation, you have `b=(a+b) * p / 100`. Multiply by 100 and divide by `(a+b)` to get `p=100 * b/(a+b)`

Answer (score 0):

`$p = $v1['b'] * (100 / ($v1['a']+$v1['b']));`